# Compositions of two rotations

Tags: matrices, rotations

Let $\Phi_1$ be the anti-clockwise rotation in  the plane about $(0,0)$ by an angle $\Theta$ and $\Phi_2$ be the anti-clockwise rotation in  the plane about $(2,0)$ by an angle $\Theta$. If $\Theta\neq n\pi$ for any integer $n$, then show that $\Phi_2\circ \Phi_1$ is a rotation about the point $\big(1, -\tan \frac{\Theta}{2}\big).$

My attempt:
We can write
$$\Phi_1(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix} \cos \Theta& -\sin \Theta\\ \sin\Theta&\cos\Theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}.$$
Also,about $(2,0)$, we can write $\Phi_2$ as $$\Phi_2(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix} \cos \Theta& -\sin \Theta\\ \sin\Theta&\cos\Theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x-2\\y\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now, for composition, we have
$$\Phi_2\circ \Phi_1(x)=\Phi_2\bigg(\begin{bmatrix} x\cos \Theta -y\sin \Theta\\ x\sin\Theta+y\cos\Theta\end{bmatrix}\bigg)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ $$
$$=\begin{bmatrix} \cos \Theta& -\sin \Theta\\ \sin\Theta&\cos\Theta\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} x\cos \Theta -y\sin \Theta-2\\ x\sin\Theta+y\cos\Theta\end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}2\\0\end{bmatrix}.$$

But I am not able to see how the composition will be a rotation around the point $\big(1, -\tan \frac{\Theta}{2}\big).$ Kindly help me or tell me where I am wrong.

Comment: Maybe try with [complex numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2838518) instead of matrices?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent
Got it. Thank you for suggesting the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this using [affine transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation#Augmented_matrix).

The rotation about the origin is

$$\small {\rm R}_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\Theta & \text{-}\sin\Theta\\
\sin\Theta & \cos\Theta\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and the rotation about $(2,0)$ is

$$\small {\rm R}_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}1 &  & 2\\
 & 1 & 0\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos\Theta & \text{-}\sin\Theta\\
\sin\Theta & \cos\Theta\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 &  & 2\\
 & 1 & 0\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}\cos\Theta & \text{-}\sin\Theta & 2-2\cos\Theta\\
\sin\Theta & \cos\Theta & -2\sin\Theta\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

You can confirm the above by multiplying the above with any coordinate point $\small \pmatrix{x \\ y \\ 1}$ and see if the results in the first two components match what you already have.

The combined transformation is

$$\begin{aligned}{\rm R}_{1}{\rm R}_{2} & =\begin{bmatrix}\cos\Theta & \text{-}\sin\Theta\\
\sin\Theta & \cos\Theta\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 &  & 2\\
 & 1 & 0\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos\Theta & \text{-}\sin\Theta\\
\sin\Theta & \cos\Theta\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 &  & -2\\
 & 1 & 0\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
 & =\begin{bmatrix}\cos2\Theta & \text{-}\sin2\Theta & 2\cos\Theta-2\cos2\Theta\\
\sin2\Theta & \cos2\Theta & 2\sin\Theta-2\sin2\Theta\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}
$$

which is indeed a rotation of $2\Theta$. The center of rotation is checked against the point $\small \pmatrix{1 \\ \mbox{-}\tan \tfrac{\Theta}{2} }$ given by finding the transformation matrix about said point and checking with the above.

$$ \small \begin{bmatrix}1 &  & 1\\
 & 1 & \text{-}\tan\tfrac{\Theta}{2}\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos2\Theta & \text{-}\sin2\Theta\\
\sin2\Theta & \cos2\Theta\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 &  & 1\\
 & 1 & \text{-}\tan\tfrac{\Theta}{2}\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}\overset{\checkmark}{=}\begin{bmatrix}\cos2\Theta & \text{-}\sin2\Theta & 2\cos\Theta-2\cos2\Theta\\
\sin2\Theta & \cos2\Theta & 2\sin\Theta-2\sin2\Theta\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix} $$

---

So the general form of rotation about a point $(t_x,t_y)$ is

$$\begin{aligned}{\rm R} & =\begin{bmatrix}1 &  & t_{x}\\
 & 1 & t_{y}\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\cos\varphi & \text{-}\sin\varphi\\
\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 &  & \text{-}t_{x}\\
 & 1 & \text{-}t_{y}\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
 & =\begin{bmatrix}\cos\varphi & \text{-}\sin\varphi & t_{x}-t_{x}\cos\varphi+t_{y}\sin\varphi\\
\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & t_{y}-t_{y}\cos\varphi-t_{x}\sin\varphi\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}\\
 & =\begin{bmatrix}\cos\varphi & \text{-}\sin\varphi & a\\
\sin\varphi & \cos\varphi & b\\
 &  & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{aligned}$$

and given $a$, $b$ values from the 3rd column we extract the pivot with

$$\left.\begin{aligned}a & =t_{x}-t_{x}\cos\varphi+t_{y}\sin\varphi\\
b & =t_{y}-t_{y}\cos\varphi-t_{x}\sin\varphi
\end{aligned}
\right\} \begin{aligned}t_{x} & =\tfrac{1}{2}\,\frac{a-a\cos\varphi-b\sin\varphi}{1-\cos\varphi}\\
t_{y} & =\tfrac{1}{2}\,\frac{b-b\cos\varphi-a\sin\varphi}{1-\cos\varphi}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: @DavidK -  I see. I can extract the center of rotation from the 3rd column though.

Comment: I'm not sure how to compute the center directly from the third column, but the way you verified it certainly works.

Comment: @DavidK - I added an addendum about how to extract the pivot point. In this case there is some amount of tedious trigonometry needed to prove the _op_ question, but with help from a CAS it can be done.